# Как передать параметры middleware в laravel из контроллера?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Mожно ли как-то передать параметры из контроллера в middleware?

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->middleware ('check.auth );
}
```

Comment: Используй сервис контейнер)

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
$this->middleware('check.auth', ['param1' => ['value1'], 'param2' => 'value2']);
```

Comment: `$this->middleware('check.auth', ['param1' => 'value1']);`